# Why i can't do "echo '#!/bin/sh" in Freebsd?

Tags: shell-script, freebsd

Why can't I do `echo '#!/bin/sh` in Freebsd? It just generates:

> /bin/sh: Event not found

I tried all combos of quotes, but nothing helps. I have only Freebsd 8.4 at hand.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the error message pointing the finger to `/bin/sh`, the problem is that your shell uses `!` to insert history into the command line, and quotes do not escape the magic of `!`. So you need to explicitly escape the `!` with a `\`.

For example:

```
echo #\!/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily turn off history expansions while you execute that command:

```
$ echo !foo
bash: !foo: event not found
$ set +H; echo !foo; set -H
!foo
```

Comment: FreeBSD does *not* use `bash` by default, but `tcsh`.